# Excel - Compare text two columns of differently formatted people names

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to evaluate two columns, one that is storing a person's name, e.g. "Ronald M. Smith" or "Kimberly R Carmen-Singh". The second column is storing an email address, like "ron_smith@email.com" and "kimberly_carmen@email.com". The goal here is to have a comparison third column, that can compare an entry from column A, to any "likely" match anywhere in column B. All emails are formatted with a general convention of firstname_lastname. Is there a good way to go about this, maybe using the LEFT function? It doesn't have to be a perfect system, just something that allows me to do a first pass/scan to identify clear outliers that aren't present.

I have tried some COUNTIF, vlookup and LEFT functions, all with no results or errors.

Comment: Maybe use FIND/SEARCH and if you have them there are some new formulas such as TEXTBEFORE which may help.

Comment: @SJR I played around with that some, but when I used something like "=SEARCH(A1,B:B)", it just returns a #SPILL! error saying that spill range is too big.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use the fuzzy joins in PowerQuery?

[image]

This definitely isn't perfect - I've set the Fuzzy Threshold at 30%.
It could probably be improved with a *transformation table* to update shortened name to their full length version - Ron to Ronald, Rich to Richard, etc.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    ChangeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Email", type text}}),
    
    //Seperate email address from domain.
    ExtractDomain = Table.AddColumn(ChangeType, "Domain", each "@" & Text.AfterDelimiter([Email], "@"), type text),
    ExtractEmail = Table.TransformColumns(ExtractDomain, {{"Email", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, "@"), type text}}),
    
    //Pull the name and email addresses into seperate tables so they can be merged again.
    EmailOnly = Table.RemoveColumns(ExtractEmail, {"Name"}),
    NameOnly = Table.RemoveColumns(ExtractEmail, {"Email", "Domain"}),
    
    //Merge the two tables.
    MergeQueries = Table.FuzzyNestedJoin(NameOnly, {"Name"}, EmailOnly, {"Email"}, "Table", JoinKind.FullOuter, [IgnoreCase=true, IgnoreSpace=true, Threshold=0.30]),
    ExpandTable = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergeQueries, "Table", {"Email", "Domain"}, {"Email", "Domain"}),
    
    //Put the email address and domain back together.
    MergeColumns = Table.CombineColumns(ExpandTable,{"Email", "Domain"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Email")
in 
    MergeColumns
```